# How to run older version of lighthouse audit?

Tags: node.js, chromium, lighthouse

[Since chrome version 79 the lighthouse audit uses a new performance scoring matrix.](https://web.dev/lighthouse-evolution-cds-2019/)
However for my project I would like to use the older version and run the test again. Under the old scoring algorithm it had a score of 90+, whereas with the new scoring I barely get 20. For administrative purposes I need to produce the report using the old scoring matrix.

**What I have tried**

So I have tried running [lighthouse node module v4.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse/v/4.3.1) since that is the last version with the older scoring matrix and my chrome is already latest version using new lighthouse 5.x.

However when I run the older lighthouse version it can't find chrome. I tried installing chromium via npm and also chrome-launcher as mentioned in the lighthouse issues.

So far the only way I managed to run lighthouse in command line is when I updated it to the latest version. Obviously it will run the latest version of lighthouse and giving me the same result as what I would have had using latest chrome dev tools.

**What I need**

How can I run an older version of lighthouse?

Answer (score 0):

If you run lighthouse with puppeteer, you can tie specific version of chrome to be use... i.e.

The Version of Puppeteer is tied to the version of chromium and therefore lighthouse will work.  I validated this setup myself.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "lighthouse": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-launcher": "^0.13.2",
    "puppeteer": "^3.0.2",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lighthouse Node CLI: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse

To install the latest version (globally): `npm i -g lighthouse`

To test your website in desktop mode and produce an HTML report (like the DEV tools): `lighthouse http://mywebsite.com --view --preset=desktop`

To test with a previous version of Lighthouse, you can use it in combination with `npx` (no need to install globally as before):

`npx -p lighthouse@7.5.0 -c 'lighthouse http://mywebsite.com --view --preset=desktop'`

Replace `7.5.0` above with the version that you want to test with. You can find all available versions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse?activeTab=versions

However please note that these tests will still be ran by whatever Chrome version you currently have installed, so results may not be the same as if you had ran it with a previous version of Chrome and the built-in Lighthouse.